# Monorepo Tsconfig Paths, How to make it work with webpack?

Tags: typescript, webpack, tsconfig

I am trying to build a monorepo with typescript, and need to import modules as same as defined in paths config.

```
"paths": {
  "@monorepo/*": ["packages/*/src"]
}
```

As per configuration, I should able to import packages like this;

```
import X from "@monorepo/web/x" !== //packages/web/src/x
```

Somehow, this config does not work. But below line works.

```
import X from "@monorepo/web/src/x" === //packages/web/src/x
```

Is there any trick to make this work?

note: all packages named like @monorepo/web @monorepo/xyz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two `*`s. One for package name, one for path in package name.

Recommend only use `*` for path in package name and list packages manually:

```
"paths": {
  "@monorepo/web/*": ["packages/web/src/*"]
  // Add more manually
}
```

Comment: After fixing some other issue alongside with your solution, it solved my problem.

Comment: Is there any way to fix path intellisense for sub packages (package/x)?  https://ibb.co/nsbm2LN. Btw, webpack compiles everything without any error. only problem is path intellisense